# React constrained input fields (e.g. number with min constraint) doesn't allow you to type in value comfortably

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Consider this simple react component that has an input field, which I'd like to constrain to have a minimum value of 20:

```
class InputTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val: 20,
    };
  }

  valChange = event => {
    let newVal = event.target.value;
    if (newVal >= 20) {
      this.setState({
        val: newVal,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type={'number'}
          value={this.state.val}
          onChange={this.valChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now everything more or less works fine with this, unless I try to type in a brand new number into the field.

e.g. if I want to select the number currently in the field and overwrite it with lets say 243.

As I highlight the number and press the "2" key, the react component rejects number 2 as it is smaller then 20, and I am unable to comfortably type the number in.

I am wondering if there already exists some kind of a solution to this.

If not I could probably build something with some kind of a delayed constraint check.

EDIT: I should have mentioned this, but I only decided to add the most simple example to make things clearer. In my case I also had a slider bound to the input field, so I'd want change the slider position as the value inside input changes and vice versa. So simply notifying the user won't work, as the slider's min and max values are what's constraining the input.

I ended up using a debounce function to delay the slider position change.

Comment: You can setState first in your handler, then call debounce function to change it once more with the custom condition.

Comment: Can you do the validation `onBlur` ?

Comment: Your test `if (newVal >= 20)` is not in the right place here because as you can see on each digit add the test return false. Why not always update the state and call the condition after and if `newVal >= 20` then you add a litte alert message on the top of your input ?

Comment: @Hoyen That only work if the user click then outside the input => not really user friendly

Comment: You might wanna `const/let/var valChange` to not make it a global.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `input` inside a `form` and add the `min` and (`max` if you want) attributes. Press `Enter` or `Submit` to see the notification (You can remove the button if you don't want it)

```html
<form>
  <input type = "number" min = 20 />
  <input type = "submit" value = "submit" />
</form>
```

And remove the condition in your `valChange` function you don't need it anymore.